# Restructure ID number in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe called Comparison_LC_Visual_Modis_2000_Forest_Forest with 21 rows. As you can see the ID numbers go from 11 to 52. I want to restructure the ID number from 1 to 21 wihtout changing the order of the rows. Somebody knows the function I can use? Thanks for your help.

```
           UNIQ_ID Driver_2000_Modis500 Driver_90_00_Visual         AREA
11    N00_E037_256                  500                 500  350497.3253
32    N00_E039_565                  500                 500  102164.9722
33    N00_E040_135                  500                 500  213035.2998
34    N00_E040_136                  500                 500  294622.1980
35    N00_E040_137                  500                 500   55298.7261
36    N00_E040_152                  500                 500  220283.8971
37    N00_E040_153                  500                 500  220283.0294
38    N00_E040_161                  500                 500   51670.9233
39    N00_E040_163                  500                 500   51670.7184
40    N00_E040_167                  500                 500    9971.4886
41    N00_E040_168                  500                 500   62548.4558
42    N00_E040_171                  500                 500   23568.8811
43    N00_E040_172                  500                 500  408832.9145
44    N00_E040_173                  500                 500   72519.6320
45    N00_E040_183                  500                 500  244752.2960
46    N00_E040_184                  500                 500   48345.4093
47    N00_E040_228                  500                 500   58924.5349
49    N00_E040_357                  500                 500  370758.6283
50    N00_E040_358                  500                 500  257445.6176
51    N00_E040_365                  500                 500  182204.3922
52    N00_E040_420                  500                 500   59225.9633
```

Comment: Those look like row numbers to me.  Try `rownames(data) <- NULL`

Comment: No problem, I switched it to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
rownames(data) <- NULL
```

where `data` is your data frame `Comparison_LC_Visual_Modis_2000_Forest_Forest` (which is a really long name for an object, btw). This will assign new row names to the data set, beginning at 1.

Comment: Do you know the function I can use whwn I create a subset in order to have the ID number from 1 to n in the output. For instancem in this line of code 'Comparison_LC_Visual_Modis_2000_Forest <- subset(Comparison_LC_Visual_Modis_2000, Comparison_LC_Visual_Modis_2000[,"Driver_90_00_Modis500"]==100)'

Answer (score -3):

```
data<-read.table(text="ID UNIQ_ID Driver_2000_Modis500 Driver_90_00_Visual         AREA
11    N00_E037_256                  500                 500  350497.3253
32    N00_E039_565                  500                 500  102164.9722
33    N00_E040_135                  500                 500  213035.2998
34    N00_E040_136                  500                 500  294622.1980
35    N00_E040_137                  500                 500   55298.7261
36    N00_E040_152                  500                 500  220283.8971
37    N00_E040_153                  500                 500  220283.0294
38    N00_E040_161                  500                 500   51670.9233
39    N00_E040_163                  500                 500   51670.7184
40    N00_E040_167                  500                 500    9971.4886
41    N00_E040_168                  500                 500   62548.4558
42    N00_E040_171                  500                 500   23568.8811
43    N00_E040_172                  500                 500  408832.9145
44    N00_E040_173                  500                 500   72519.6320
45    N00_E040_183                  500                 500  244752.2960
46    N00_E040_184                  500                 500   48345.4093
47    N00_E040_228                  500                 500   58924.5349
49    N00_E040_357                  500                 500  370758.6283
50    N00_E040_358                  500                 500  257445.6176
51    N00_E040_365                  500                 500  182204.3922
52    N00_E040_420                  500                 500   59225.9633",header=T)

data
data$ID<-order(data$ID)

data
```

Comment: There is no `ID` column in the original data